# LTSP + AD Integration

Tags: active-directory, ltsp

I have a Windows AD environment with user profiles having homedirs in Windows.
Now I have setup an Ubuntu LTSP Server (10.04.3 - installed via ubuntu-alternate 64bit)

My target was to integrate both these environments, have a single sign-on feature and having their homedirs mapped in Linux as well.

For this purpose I came across this tutorial
http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~hafidi/t...n_windows.html
This exactly suites the kind of environment that I have.

However in this tutorial, I am stuck at Step No. 5.2.2
It says to run authconfig
I don't know what they are referring to here.
I have auth-config-server and auth-config-client installed on ubuntu but still running just authconfig in terminal doesn't work.
Am I missing something here?

Please help me out.
If there are any other robust free solutions, please also let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I cannot view the URL you provided above, so my suggestion is to review this article http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-active-directory-integration-with-centrify-directcontrol-express-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot.html (the directions are applicable to 10.04 as well). You can get Centrify Express through the Ubuntu repository or directly from http://www.centrify.com/express.   Specifically Centrify Express has part of the install process a utility called "adcheck" that does various tests to determine if your system can be properly joined to an Active Directory domain.  Running this command will probably debug your issue.  So even if you elect not to go ahead and use Centrify Express, at least it will do a pre-install check to validate your environment.  If you do install Centrify Express, be sure to run the adinfo command to validate that the Ubuntu system is properly joined.

Hope this helps.  JS